# Enterprise Architect shows Pop-Up when using API through C#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am using enterprise architect version 15 and I have created one file based project with .eapx file Extension. I am trying to create and update new package via API (using C# language) in enterprise architect with following hierarchy: Root Model/Package/New Package and while **Updating the package** I am getting following pop of **underlying model has been changed**, which freezes my enterprise architect to respond to any further API calls.

[image: pop-up from Enterprise architect]

**Following is the order of execution(Here every step is an separate function which passes the newPackage that is created):**

**1. First create a package with name 'Demo'**

```
Package newPackage = package.Packages.AddNew(EAConstants.OH_CREATE_TEMPLATE, "Package");
newPackage.Update();
```

**2. Set the system field values.**

```
Package package = (Package)newPackage;
package.Element.Status = "Approved"
package.Element.Stereotype = <Some Stereotype Value>;
package.Element.Update();
package.Update();
```

**3. Set tagged values**

```
Package pc = (Package)newPackage;
Element element = pc.Element;
set tag values for element
element.TaggedValues.Refresh();
element.Update();
```

**4. Update name of the new package**

```
Package changePackage = (Package)newPackage
changePackage.Name = "NewName"
changePackage.Update();
```

**5. Refresh package**

```
Package package = (Package)newPackage
newPackage.Element.Refresh();
newPackage.Update();
```

**Tried things:**

1. Tried to refresh all the models after each update step.
2. Tried to refresh all the model before each update step.

**Expectations:**
Avoid the pop-up displaying warning message, because it freezes my enterprise application for any further API calls (More suitable approach: avoid using suppress dialog box method for package).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is happening because all of the superfluous `Update()` and `Refresh()` calls.

You really shouldn't execute code unless you know for sure you need it.

Examples:

```
Package package = (Package)newPackage;
package.Element.Status = "Approved"
package.Element.Stereotype = <Some Stereotype Value>;
package.Element.Update();
package.Update();
```

There no need for the last `package.Update()` since you didn't change anything to the package object, and you already saved the `package.Element`

```
Package pc = (Package)newPackage;
Element element = pc.Element;
set tag values for element
element.TaggedValues.Refresh();
element.Update();
```

This code does nothing (functional) at all. No need for either `Refresh()` or `element.Update()`

```
Package package = (Package)newPackage
newPackage.Element.Refresh();
newPackage.Update();
```

Again, this code does nothing at all.

If you limit your code to only those things you actually need, you will have a better chance at avoiding these annoying popups.

There's also a property to delay GUI updates (`Repository.EnableUIUpdates`), and a method to tell EA something has changed (`Repository.AdviseElementChange (long ObjectID)`). Those might help as well if all else fails.